# Trying to use ID in MySQL SubSubQuery

Tags: mysql, subquery

So I'll show you what I'm trying to do and explain my problem, there may be an answer different to the approach I'm trying to take.

The query I'm trying to perform is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM report_keywords rk
WHERE rk.report_id = 231
AND (
    SELECT SUM(t.conv) FROM (
        SELECT conv FROM report_keywords t2 WHERE t2.campaign_id = rk.campaign_id ORDER BY conv DESC LIMIT 10
    ) t
) >= 30
GROUP BY rk.campaign_id
```

The error I get is

```
Unknown column 'rk.campaign_id' in 'where clause'
```

Obviously this is saying that the table alias rk is not making it to the subsubquery.  What I'm trying to do is get all of the campaigns where the sum of the top 10 conversions is greater than or equal to 30.

The relevant table structure is:

```
id INT,
report_id INT,
campaign_id INT,
conv INT
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks to Kickstart I was able to do what I wanted. Here's my final query:

```
SELECT campaign_id, SUM(conv) as sum_conv
FROM (
    SELECT campaign_id, conv, @Sequence := if(campaign_id = @campaign_id, @Sequence + 1, 1) AS aSequence, @campaign_id := campaign_id
    FROM report_keywords
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Sequence :=  0, @campaign_id := 0) Sub1
    WHERE report_id = 231
    ORDER BY campaign_id, conv DESC
) t
WHERE aSequence <= 10
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING sum_conv >= 30
```

Comment: Try using the innerquery on the outer select rather than in where clause, as the aggregation function would not work inside the where clause and put the condition in the where clause on the calculated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly use a user variable to add a sequence number to get the latest 10 records for each one, then use SUM to get the count of those.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT rk.*
FROM report_keywords rk
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT campaign_id, SUM(conv) AS SumConv
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT campaign_id, conv, @Sequence := if(campaign_id = @campaign_id, @Sequence + 1, 1) AS aSequence, @campaign_id := campaign_id
        FROM report_keywords
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Sequence :=  0, @campaign_id := "") Sub1
        ORDER BY campaign_id, conv
    ) Sub2
    WHERE aSequence <= 10
    GROUP BY campaign_id
) Sub3
ON rk.campaign_id = Sub3.campaign_id AND Sub3.SumConv >= 30
WHERE rk.report_id = 231
```